# The relation between trace and determinant of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, trace

Let $M$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix.

Is there any equality or inequality that relates the trace and determinant of $M$?

Comment: Also probably not what you're looking for but I feel should be here: $\det(M)=\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}(\bigwedge^n M)$. $M$ need not be symmetric.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The determinant and the trace are two quite different beasts, little relation can be found among them.

If the matrix is not only symmetric (hermitic) but also *positive semi-definite*, then its eigenvalues are real and non-negative.
Hence, [given the properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Eigenvalue_relationships) ${\rm tr}(M)=\sum \lambda_i$ and ${\rm det}(M)=\prod \lambda_i$, and recalling the [AM GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), we get the following (probably not very useful) inequality:

$$\frac{{\rm tr}(M)}{n} \ge {\rm det}(M)^{1/n}$$

(equality holds iff $M = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda \ge  0$)

Much more interesting/insightful/useful are the answers by [Owen Sizemore](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2083444/312) and [Rodrigo de Azevedo](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2083801/312).

Comment: n is the order of the matrix ($M_{n\times n}$) right?

Comment: Yes, I'm following the question statement.

Comment: What does positive definite mean here can anyone tell me?  Matrix without a symmetric one can be positive definite ?

Answer (score 87):

Not exactly what you're looking for but I would be remiss not to mention that for any complex square matrix $A$ the following identity holds:

$$\det(e^A)=e^{\mbox{tr}(A)} $$

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but why doesn’t this answer the question? (I up voted it because it was exactly what I was looking for, but should I?)

Comment: @TheoreticalPerson Strictly speaking, this does not answer the question because the equation does not relate $\tr(A)$ with $\det(A)$. However, the equation is certainly important and elegant, and in some sense one can argue that it really answers "the spirit" of the question.

Comment: how come it doesn't answer how trace and determinant isn't related?

Comment: Does it mean, absolute value of the exponent is equal to the exponent of the real part?

Comment: @Rainb Because it relates $\det(e^A)$ with $\text{tr}(A)$ and not $\det(A)$ with $\text{tr}(A)$.

Comment: The special linear Lie algebra $\mathfrak {sl}(n,\mathbb F)$ of $n \times n$ matrices of trace $0$ generates the special linear group (matrices with determinant $1$).

Answer (score 72):

The trace of $\bf M$ is the **directional derivative** of the determinant in the direction of $\bf M$ at ${\bf I}_n$, i.e.,

$$ \det \left( {\bf I}_n + h {\bf M} \right) = 1 + h \, \mbox{tr} ({\bf M}) + O \left( h^2 \right) $$

In Tao's words, "near the identity, the determinant behaves like the trace"$^\color{red}{\star}$. More generally,

$$\det( {\bf A} + h {\bf B} ) = \det({\bf A})  + h \, \mbox{tr} \left( \mbox{adj} ({\bf A}) \, {\bf B} \right) + O \left(h^2\right)$$

which is a variation of [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula). Note that it is not required that $\bf M$ be symmetric.

---

<sub>$\color{red}{\star}$ Terence Tao, [Matrix identities as derivatives of determinant identities](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/), January 13, 2013.</sub>

Comment: While this is true, it has nothing to do with the question!

Comment: The OP asked for a relation between determinant and trace. I gave him one. Nowhere was it written that derivatives were not allowed.

Comment: He wants an inequality or an equality involving the trace and the determinant of a symmetric matrix. What you wrote does not provide that.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo "the OP asked for relation between determinant and trace." Not. "the trace and determinant of M", the determinant and the trace of the **same** matrix (linear operator).

Answer (score 28):

No, there is not.  Consider the matrix with parameter $n$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & n \\
    n      &1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
The trace is 2, while the determinant is $1-n^2$.  You can vary $n$ to violate any possible inequality between the trace and the determinant.

Comment: it is not a symmetric matrix

Comment: @TPArrow I will edit.

Comment: so under what condition we can find a relation between trace and determinant?

Comment: Even when the matrix is diagonal: there is no relation between a sum of numbers and their product.

Comment: $2 > 1-n^2$ always holds! In fact, in dimension 2, you *can* say something: see [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2083694/14972)

Comment: It doesn't hold if $n = 2i$.

Comment: @Erik It is pretty rare to use the term "symmetric" (rather than "Hermitian" or "self-adjoint") when working with complex matrices.  I doubt anyone looking for inequalities is referring to anything but the real case.

Comment: @ErickWong - you are might be correct, about the rarity of that, but I've had times where I was working with a complex symmetric (non-Hermitian) matrices. In any case, the text in this answer is correct - given that matrix $n$ can be varied to violate any possible inequality.

Answer (score 27):

Due to OP's fairly general formulation there's diverse bunch of answers by now. In addition to these, I'd like to mention some concrete **relations expressing the determinant in terms of traces**. They hold without the symmetry hypothesis, just assume dealing with a general complex matrix.

Despite being "quite different beasts", both $\det(M)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(M)$ of an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ are given by some $n$-variable symmetric polynomial, evaluated at the eigenvalues of $M$.

> For any fixed matrix size $n$ there's a polynomial in $n$ variables, of total degree $n$, which yields $\det(M)$ when evaluated at
>   $\left(\operatorname{tr}(M^n),\operatorname{tr}(M^{n-1}),\ldots,\operatorname{tr}(M)\right)$:
>   $$
> \det M\; =\;
> \begin{cases}
> \operatorname{tr}M & n=1\\[1.67ex]
> \frac{1}{2}\big((\operatorname{tr}M)^2
>  - \operatorname{tr}\left(M^2\right)\big) & n=2\\[1.67ex]
> \frac{1}{6}\big((\operatorname{tr}M)^3
>  - 3\operatorname{tr}\left(M^2\right)(\operatorname{tr}M)
>  + 2\operatorname{tr}\left(M^3\right)\big) & n= 3\\[1.67ex]
>  \quad\ldots & n\ge4
> \end{cases}
> $$

Case $\mathbf{n=1}$ is clear.

$\mathbf{n=2}$ is straightforward when applying Cayley-Hamilton to $M$
$$
M^2\:-\:(\operatorname{tr}M)\:M\:+\:(\det M)\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1}\;=\;\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}
$$
and taking the trace.
Referring to Paul's answer/example featuring
$M=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&k\\ k&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,
thus $M^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1+k^2&2k\\ 2k&1+k^2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,
one obtains
$$\det M\;=\;\frac{1}{2}\big(4-2(1+k^2)\big) = 1-k^2$$
for the sake of illustration, presumably not the quickest way towards $\det(M)$
(the parameter has been renamed to $k$ since $n$ denotes the matrix size).

Cases $\mathbf{n\ge3}$ get more expensive $\ldots$ and are available:
A suitable entry point is the corresponding [subsection in the Wikipedia entry on determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Relation_to_eigenvalues_and_trace).

---

If you clicked the preceding link then you may scroll down just a bit to get into a det-tr-inequality for a positive-definite matrix, also worthwhile as answer to the OP. Or skip [directly down to it ;-)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Upper_and_lower_bounds)

Answer (score 23):

Up to sign, the trace and determinant of an $n \times n$ matrix are coefficients of its characteristic polynomial (specifically, the coefficients in degrees $n-1$ and $0$ respectively).

The only constraint that the matrix being symmetric adds is that the characteristic polynomial is totally real — that is, all of its roots are real.

(note every totally real polynomial is a characteristic polynomial; e.g. of the diagonal matrix whose entries are the roots)

Thus, your problem is equivalent to

> Let $f$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ whose roots are all real.  Is there any relationship between the coefficient in degree $n-1$ and the constant coefficient?

I believe you can only say anything when $n \leq 2$. When $n=2$, the requirement that the roots be real implies that $\mathrm{tr}(M)^2 \geq 4 \det(M)$.

Comment: Just to elaborate on the last point for the OP's benefit, the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial for $n = 2$ are, up to sign, exactly $\operatorname{tr} M$ and $\det M$; looking at the discriminant gives the indicated inequality. For higher $n$, there are more terms in the minimal polynomial.

Comment: +1 I was looking through the answers to post exactly this if no one had already!

Answer (score 9):

The only relation I can think of is this one : Since the matrix $A$ is symetric, it is diagonalizable, thus it can be written $A = P^{-1}DP$ where $D$ is diagonal and $P$ is invertible. Therefore $$\det A = \prod_{i = 1} ^n \lambda_i$$ and $$tr A = \sum_{i = 1} ^n \lambda_i$$ where $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue.

Some inequalities can be found between the sum and the product.

Comment: Note that these equalities are true in general and do not require symmetry or diagonalizability; this can i.e. be seen by trigonalisation in C.

Comment: You're right, this comes from the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Another way of expressing this relationship: $$\left .\frac {d}{d\lambda} \det(A + \lambda I)\right |_{\lambda = 0} = \operatorname{tr}(A)$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair No, the derivative should be the trace of the *adjugate* of $A$ rather than the trace of $A$.

Comment: @user1551 - Gah - you're right. What I was intending is $$\left .\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\frac {d^{n-1}}{d\lambda^{n-1}} \det(A + \lambda I)\right |_{\lambda = 0} = \operatorname{tr}(A)$$, but I went for the wrong coefficient of the characteristic polynomial.