# Which relationship between trace and determinant is established using density?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, determinant, trace

I read in some lecture notes that "as an example for the intersection between linear algebra and calculus, one can establish the relationship between trace and determinant of a matrix using a density-argument".

Which relationship is meant? And what would the argument be?

Comment: Perhaps they're referring to the formula
$$
\det\exp(A) = \exp(\operatorname{trace}(A))
$$

Comment: Another notable relationship is
$$
\det ( I_n + hA) = 1 + h \, \mbox{tr} (A) + O (h^2)
$$
some other suggestions can be taken from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2083410/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, are these really known for being verifiable using density? Thank you for the link, it was helpful.

Comment: the first one certainly is.  Not sure about the second off the top of my head

Comment: Yes, I now think they must have meant the first one... Thank you @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, it can be seen that the set of diagonalizable matrices is dense in the set of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. So, when you have a continuous operation on $n \times n$ matrices, you can look at what it does to diagonal matrices and then argue that any other matrix is arbitrarily close to a diagonal matrix in some basis and then use limits to prove the result. For example, $\mathrm{det}$ is continuous on $n \times n$ matrices because the formula is given by a multivariate polynomial. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I think that in combination with the first comment of @Omnomnomnom this answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Ramen  You're welcome.